# can't cast result of JSON to an NSDictionary? How do I debug?

Tags: ios, json, swift

I have a request:

```
 let authRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: self.authUrl!)
        authRequest.HTTPMethod = "POST"
        var params = ["email": "me@email.com", "password": "password"] as Dictionary<String, String>
        var err: NSError?
        authRequest.HTTPBody = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(params, options: nil, error: &err)
        authRequest.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        authRequest.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

        let authSession = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(authRequest, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
          println("Response: \(response)")
          var strData = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
          println("Body: \(strData)")
          var err: NSError?
          let parsedObject: AnyObject? = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data,
            options: nil,
            error:&err)
          if let fullObject = parsedObject as? NSDictionary {
            println("I am a dictionary")
          } else {
            println("O GOD WHY")
          }
        })
       authSession.resume()
```

I'm afraid I can't show you the entirety of the data as that would provide insight into my companies authentication and user model. However, two things are worthy of note:

1) strData prints as Body: 
Optional([{

2) The JSON structure is complex, containing multiple keys which map to integers, strings, objects (`{}`), arrays (`[]`) as well as arrays of objects and objects within objects.

response and data get printed out and are valid JSON, however data fails to cast to a dictionary. No error message is printed. How can I go about debugging this? Any ideas as to why this is happening?

Comment: Can you show your output also? Because I doubt it's an NSDictionary. Your code looks good.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't actually provide the data as that would give insight into my employers database schema. I have gone into a little bit of detail above. in my edit. Do you have any thoughts on at least the kinds of thing that might be causing this? Or at least how I could track this down?

Comment: Is it a valid json? You can check it from `http://jsonlint.com`. I think the information you have provided is too short to diagnosis the problem..

Comment: Is your top-level really a dictionary? Giving the top level entry (with renaming could be interesting) Does `err` contains something?

Comment: *"strData prints as Body: Optional([{"* - The leading **square bracket `[`** clearly shows that the top-level object is an **array** and not a dictionary.

Comment: it is valid json. The top level is an array Thank you! So many bad habits from years of Duck Typed languages. Thanks for your help!

Comment: one more question. Changing the let o as? Array<NSDictionary> generates an array of dictionaries where both the keys and values are memory addresses (0x000....) how can I convert this to dictionaries of actual key values? Additionally printing it(the array) from the expression console resuls in <error: use of undeclared identifier 'cocoarr'

Comment: Also feel free to write up an answer for points ;)

Comment: being more explicit with the casting (Array<Dictionary<String, AnyObject>> instead of Array<NSDictionary>) made the problem go away. Not 100% clear as to how/why